# how to concatenate two tensors whose dimensions values differ on the dimension 0

Tags: tensorflow, concatenation

I have two tensors with different shapes, in one it is shape=(None, 20, 32) and in another, it is shape=(None, 5, 32). Let say the first is the embedding of 20 words and the second is the embeddings of 5 words. Now I would like to contact them and have a tensor with the shape of (None, 25, 32). When I try tf.concat([t1,t2], 0) I get the following exception: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 20 and 5

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `None` will represent the same number of samples, you just need to specify that concatenation axis to be 1.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.random.uniform((4, 5, 32))
b = tf.random.uniform((4, 20, 32))

tf.concat([a, b], axis=1).shape
```

```
TensorShape([4, 25, 32])
```